# symfony queryBuilder Where IN

Tags: symfony

Hi all i have problem and don't know what to do.

```
public function getOrderCityByPrefix($data)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('w')
        ->where('w.orderCity IN (:data)')
        ->setParameter('data', $data)
        ->getQuery();

    return $queryBuilder->getResult();
}
```

Controller:

```
$cities = json_decode($request->get('cities'), true); // if return i get The controller must return a response (Array(0 => 'VLN', 1 => 'KNS') given)
```

if i get this responce `Array(0 => 'VLN', 1 => 'KNS')` and put to function i get well result which i need. But if i put variable `$cities` to function i have empty result.

```
$cities = json_decode($request->get('cities'), true);

if(!empty($cities)){
    $orders = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()  
                   ->getRepository('AppBundle:OrderWork')
                   ->getOrderCityByPrefix([0 => 'VLN', 1 => 'KNS']); // it's good 

    $orders = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
                   ->getRepository('AppBundle:OrderWork')
                   ->getOrderCityByPrefix($cities); // bad
}
```

Comment: what if you try with: `->getOrderCityByPrefix([0, 1]);` ?

Comment: i solved this problem, it was because VLN and KNS was in "'VLN'"  and "'KNS'" remove "" and always ok